# Find minimum cost among nodes

Tags: data-structures, graph, neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have three destinations A, B, and C and associate travel cost between A to B, B to A, A to C, C to A, B to C and C to B and all are different. I have to search the particular location among A, B, and C where the other two will come and the cost will minimize. e.g., A and B can come to C location. And How it can be optimized for N location?

Answer (score 0):

I would claim that this problem is in O(|V|^{2}) and you would therefore have to check the travel cost for each node. Pick a node, check the travel cost of the other n-1 nodes to this node and do this for every node while maintaining the one with the least travel cost.